# global modules in node.js

Tags: node.js, global

I have made a custom error class for throwing error in node.js. I want to use this class in my entire project. But the problem is wherever I need to use first I have to require in that file and then use this class which is quite tedious. Anyone any idea how to make it global so that all the modules can use it without requiring it in every file.

This is a custom error class file "cti_error.js"

```
'use strict';
class CTIError extends Error {
    constructor (status,message,details='') {
        super(message)
        this.name = status
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
        this.status = status || 500;
        this.details = details?details:message;
        this.reason = message;
    }
}
module.exports = CTIError;
```

My project structure:-

```
my_project
|
|____utility
|       |
|       |____cti_error.js
|
|____routes
|      |
|      |_____product.js
|      |_____defects.js
|
|
|_____server.js
```

The solution what I know is to require the custom error class as below in every file where I want to throw an error:-

```
const cti_error = require('../../utility/cti_error.js');
throw new cti_error(403,"wrong details");
```

Any idea how to use cti_eror without requiring in every file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign it to nodejs's `global` variable.

Like this:

```
global.CTIError = CTIError;
```

Now you can access the `CTIError` anywhere as:

```
new CTIError()
```

Your linter might tell you that `CTIError` is not declared though.

Comment: is there any other way where I can import the file in server.js and can be able to use it throughout the project?

Comment: Yeah thats the way, to do it, your `server.js` would just need to have this code:
`const cti_error = require('../../utility/cti_error.js');
global.cti_error = cti_error;`
That will make `cti_error` accessible throughout the project.

Comment: so you are saying that I should require in server.js and export it globally from cti_err class

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "export it globally from cti_err class". But yes you should require `cti_err` in `server.js` and assign `cti_err` to nodejs's `global` variable.

Comment: It's not working, its giving an error as "cti_error is not defined"

Comment: how to assign cti_error to nodejs's global variable?

Comment: Did you add this `global.cti_error = cti_error` in your server.js?

Comment: my server.js is having code
    cti_error = require('./utility/cti_error.js');

my product.js is having code
    throw new cti_error(403,"wrong details for a");

and my cti_error is having code:-
'use strict';
class CTIError extends Error {
    constructor (status,message,details='') {
        super(message)
        this.name = status
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
        this.status = status || 500;
        this.details = details?details:message;
        this.reason = message;
    }
}
global.CTIError = CTIError;

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214057/discussion-between-zishone-and-sweta-sharma).